# Missing touch events when work is done in UI thread

Tags: android, event-handling, touch-event, motionevent

I'm developing an Android keyboard, which basically is a custom `LinearLayout` (named `KeyboardView`) with `LinearLayout`s (representing rows) that has a set of `TextView`s (representing the keys). If it should be represented in XML it would be something like:

```
<KeyboardView>       <!-- extends LinearLayout -->
    <LinearLayout>   <!-- row #1 -->
        <TextView /> <!-- key #1 -->
        ...          <!-- more TextViews -->
    </LinearLayout>
    ...              <!-- more rows/LinearLayouts -->
</KeyboardView>
```

In `KeyboardView` I override `onTouchEvent` and if the user touches within the bounds of one of the `TextViews`, a controller is called (and that controller figures out how the key should be treated). This means that the children of `KeyboardView` never gets the focus-event. It is done in this way for various reason, e.g. so swiping in the keyboard can be handled.

This works fine in most cases, but we got some reports about the keyboard not always reacting on all touch events. It can be hard to reproduce that behavior, but we've confirmed it wasn't caused by the user touching in the gap between the keys (since there's no gaps), so a thought was that we in some case take too much time to figure out what should be done with the key - the execution time of `onTouchEvent` could simply be too long.

To test this theory out, I ended up adding some `Thread.sleep`s to the `onTouchEvent` (in order to simulate a lot of work being done). This seemed to somehow reproduce the issue, since it's clear that not all touch-events are received. It seems like the system has some kind of queue such that some of the events are received, but some are ignored. I e.g. made a simple keyboard with only the keys `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and a sleep of 2 seconds. When pressing them one after each other only touch events (`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`) for `A`, `B` and `D` are recieved. In some cases `ACTION_CANCEL` is however received.

In order to exaggerate the problem, I tried setting the sleep to 5 seconds, and clicking a second key during the sleep of the first key touch. In that case, no events for the the second click is ever received - but all of the touch events for the first key are received.

For the above scenario the three received events are as follows (when outputted to the log). Note that the second key click (which are never received) are between log #1 and #2:

```
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=536.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=116942926, downTime=116942926, deviceId=8, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=536.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=116942992, downTime=116942926, deviceId=8, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=536.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=116942999, downTime=116942926, deviceId=8, source=0x1002 }
```

I have no clue if it's just a part of the Android framework or I'm missing something. I could "just" put the work done `onTouchEvent` into a thread, but I would be afraid it just covers the real issue and I would in general prefer to avoid threads if possible. I've also tried overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` and always letting it return `true` (to try to avoid `ACTION_CANCEL`), but `ACTION_CANCEL` still occured in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Touch events can be combined, especially move events.  Are you checking for that?

There's 0 chance of touch events just being totally skipped, the framework doesn't do that.   Combining does happen if its the same type. Also, if you get a CANCEL, it means that the touch events are going to another view and you won't recieve any more until all fingers are lifted-  so if you're seeing cancel you should figure out who's stealing your touches.  onInterceptTouchEvent will not fix that, as that only effects calls on your children, not on you.  If anything it would make things worse.

Also, check for ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_UP.  These occur instead of up and down if multiple fingers touch at once.  You may be accidentally causing these (or the screen may be misregistering, especially if you're almost touching there can sometimes be stray capacitance).

Comment: Interesting thought with the multi-tap. It does however not seem to be the case (if I understand it correctly). I've updated the post with log-output that states the three Motion Events in the second case (with 5 second sleep) and it seems like there's only one pointer in all three cases.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that some events are ignored when I set it up like this. When adding a sleep of 5 seconds the system outputs this (followed by a list of what uses the CPU):

```
2019-06-11 17:06:45.200 905-990/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in [my_app_identifier]
PID: 10365
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 12.  Wait queue head age: 5490.6ms.)
Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
CPU usage from 284899ms to 0ms ago (2019-06-11 17:02:00.002 to 2019-06-11 17:06:44.902) with 99% awake:
```

This is what I assume leads to some events unfortunally being ignored. And therefore sleeping the thread isn't a valid test in this case.

In the end I got inspired by the answer by Gabe Sechan since it's logic that when the user types fast they might touch with another finger before lifting the last one. So now we also support `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` and `ACTION_POINTER_UP` and this seems to be working a lot better.